# Color a cell if the previous cell is a different day in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to color the first date when it is different from the previous cell?

Can somebody please share an example? THANK YOU

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: Do you mean conditional formatting, using a formula like `=$A3<>$A2`?

Answer (score 0):

When writing conditional formatting address like `$A$3` refer to absolute cells, but `A3` refer to cells relative to the first of your conditional formatting range.

So on range `$A$3:$A20` you can add a custom formula rule with formula `=A2<A3`